# Google sheets query & fix number of rows as result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to format a table with the result of a query. My table shall be 15 rows long. Sometimes my query returns less rows. Is there an easy way to initialize the remaining rows to 0 (or any other value or string)?

I tried to initialize all rows first but the query does not expand due to these init values.

Hope I'm clear (the purpose is then to display a chart and if values are not present my series are shifted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  {
    QUERY(data, "SELECT ... LIMIT 15", 0);
    SEQUENCE(15, 1, 0, 0)
  },
  15,
  1
)
```

Assuming you have only one column as the result of `QUERY`. If more, then set the 2nd parameter of `SEQUENCE` to that number.

Comment: Very good solution, many thanks @kishkin! I adapted to my Sheets where I have also data to be transposed in rows. The only trick is to do the Transpose at the end (and not just after the query). Again, thanks!